# Blazor iframe not working with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, polyfills

I am currently working on a Blazor ASP.NET CORE 3.1 application that needs to work on IE11. I am trying to view a PDF from the PDF binary. I have added tried adding blazor.polyfill.js and blazor.polyfill.min.js to the project and it makes the rest of the application work, but it doesn't allow me to view PDFs in the iframe. Below is a picture of the code I have.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsrrk.png

I am trying to set the src of the iframe as a pdf binary. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to get this to work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/internet-explorer-11-end-of-support

Answer (score 0):

Please first make sure any kind (for example, a simple string) of iframe contents work for you. If you still have the problem afterwards, try to reproduce it here: https://blazorfiddle.com/
This will also enable the community to assist you.